# How to check if two qgsPoints are equal in PyQgis

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have two points:

```
a=QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(227739,908343))
b=QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(227739,908343))
```

but when I run:

```
a==b
```

it returns False. 
What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

it returns True when I only use:

```
a=(QgsPoint(227739,908343))
b=(QgsPoint(227739,908343))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `==`, just use the following command:

```
a=QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(227739,908343))
b=QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(227739,908343))

a.equals(b)    # -> returns True
```

**EDIT**:
Regarding to the comments on this answer:

```
 a = QgsPoint(227739,908343)
 b = QgsPoint(227739,908343)
 a == b # TRUE
 aa = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(a)
 bb = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(b)
 aa.equals(bb) # TRUE
```

Try to investigate the type of your points (are they really QgsPoints?) and if it still doesn't work, than compare the values manually

```
a.x() == b.x()
```

Comment: on a (un)related note,can you help me with this too?
'qaz[0]
(227739,908343)
type(qaz[0])
<class 'qgis.core.QgsPoint'>
wxs[0]
(227739,908343)
type(wxs[0])
<class 'qgis.core.QgsPoint'>
qaz[0]==wxs[0]
False'

Comment: so what is the output of qaz[0].equals(wxs[0]) ?

Comment: AttributeError: 'QgsPoint' object has no attribute 'equals'

Comment: so add the same code before your point to get a QgsGeometry Object --> a = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(qaz[0])

Comment: >>> q= QgsGeometry.fromPoint(qaz[0])
>>> w= QgsGeometry.fromPoint(wxs[0])

q.equals(w)
False

Comment: I appreciate your help, maybe there is sth wrong with my installation or other parts of my script and I have to figure it out on my own

Comment: See my edit to the Answer. Investigate your types and the system setup and f you still account this error, than raise another question :)

Comment: Thanks! your tip helped me to find the problem:

>>> wxs[0].x()
227738.54377
>>> qaz[0].x()
227738.5437723927

Answer (score 1):

**IN QGIS 3.0**

```
a=QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(227739,908343))
b=QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(227739,908343))
```

`a.asPoint() == b.asPoint()` returns True